# How to close mysql connections explicitly in zend framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I'm successfully using ZF2.2
Everything was working fine until a requirement arised to close the sql connection explicitly.
I know PHP closes all extra db connections after some time.
But I wanted to do this explicity something like $adapter->closeConnection();

Please tell me there is something which can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the adapter in `$adapter`, this should work:

```
 $adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->disconnect();
```

Comment: Thanks your solution worked but I still had to increase the max allowed connestions in mysqld file.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the db_adapter and then get the connection (getConnection()) and with this object you will be able to use the disconnect() method.